# Problems with Python speech_recognition and PyAudio

Tags: python, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, pyaudio

Hi I'm trying to run this simple script:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r=sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
  print "Say something."
  audio = r.listen(source)

print r.recognize_sphinx(audio)
```

It's practically a copy of the example in the speech_recognition tar file, but I get this output:

```
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835.pcm.front.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM front
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround21
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround21
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835.pcm.surround40.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround40
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround41
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround50
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround51
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835.pcm.surround71.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround71
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM iec958
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM spdif
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM spdif
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
Expression 'paInvalidSampleRate' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2048
Expression 'PaAlsaStreamComponent_InitialConfigure( &self->capture, inParams, self->primeBuffers, hwParamsCapture, &realSr )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2719
Expression 'PaAlsaStream_Configure( stream, inputParameters, outputParameters, sampleRate, framesPerBuffer, &inputLatency, &outputLatency, &hostBufferSizeMode )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2843
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mic.py", line 4, in <module>
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 117, in __enter__
    input = True, # stream is an input stream
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/pyaudio.py", line 750, in open
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/pyaudio.py", line 441, in __init__
IOError: [Errno -9997] Invalid sample rate
```

It obviously says that the  problem is an Invalid sample rate but it also talks about Evaluation errors and being unable to find definitions like its trying to use the wrong microphone or something.  It's hard to find any docs on this so if someone could help me on even how to define a sample rate if that's even the true problem, that would be awesome!